# How to automatically save files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure

I have a neural network and am generating figures and I wish to save those figures automatically with the filename as the training function and the hidden layer size, as well as the percentage correct

I have the following

```
... trainFcn=trainscg
```

This changes between a couple of options: scg, rp, lm, etc

I also have the

```
hiddenLayerSize=[10 10 10]
```

These values also change often.

I run my neural network and output a confusion matrix:

```
figure, plotconfusion(nnOutput, target)
```

I then do

```
saveas(gcf, trainFcn+hiddenLayerSize)
```

This does not work when I add the variables like that and also fails when I put a comma instead of a plus. How can I make this saveas work and make the filename my variables? I don't need to have the accuracy in the filename but if I can then it'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

Your method does not work because the function expects a string as a filename but `trainFcn+hiddenLayerSize` is not one. Try the following:

```
% convert size vector to a string
sizeString = sprintf('%dx', hiddenLayerSize);
sizeString = sizeString(1:end-1); % removes the trailing x
% auto-generate your filename
filename = sprintf('%s_%s', func2str(trainFcn), sizeString);
saveas(gcf, filename);
```

This assumes that you have defined `trainFcn` like `trainFcn = @trainscg;` or something similar.

Comment: I have defined trainFcn=trainscg, but your code does not work. I get an error in the filename=sprintf portion. I also tried just doing saveas(gcf, func2str(trainFcn)) but that also did not work

Comment: You have to pass the function name as a handle so you would need to define `trainFcn = @trainscg` and not the way you have done it. `func2str` only works on function handles. How are you using trainFcn in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I ended up using num2str and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: If the answer helped you, please remember to mark it as "Accepted" to thank the author and improve SO :)